# Passing PartialView through child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I'm new to MVC, and now I'm trying to understand the conception of partial views. So, the question is: Does client fully recieve a a whole markup of new html page, when I'm passing a PartialViewRezult from controller to a View by child action. May be it uses AJAX?

Comment: There is no ajax involved. Its not clear what your asking. Using `@Html.Action()` in a view just calls a controller method and inserts the partial view it returns into the main view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, If you are returning a PartialView to/from an action method then It will return only markup available in your PartialView. It will not wrap your partial view markup in html or body tag. and There is no ajax involved to render a partial view unless you are using an explicit Ajax call.